# C# - Design questions about a server firing push notifications to clients - how to implement?

Tags: c#, xmpp

This is the scenario.

I have multiple clients on our application, and one server.
The server is itself disconnected from the clients, it just downloads some data from the web via a windows service (web services and FTP), processes the data and updates a database to which all the clients are connected and draw data from.

I would like to be able to actively notify the clients, and with a certain degree of granularity, when some downloading occurs (i.e. only the Traders when a price/trade update occurs, or only the Engineers when there's something for them) without polling.

The server should fire up a notification to all the connected clients instead of having them continuously "ask" if there is an update, because in this case I would have to maintain state on all the clients.

I thought about XMPP, with Matrix.

To do so each client has to open a persistent connection with the windows service, but I lack the exact details on how to implement this. MAybe with nodes!
For what I understand XMPP is perfect for what I want to accomplish and gives me the extensibility to grow to some more functionality if I have the need to.

I don't know if to implement my own server or use one of the existing one (I hear jabberd2 has an excellent windows server).

But most important: I need suggestions on A) an XMPP server to run on Windows and B) a C# library. Besides Matrix I have found very few, and above all I need notifications support (pubsub).

Comment: Have you looked at MQs? Examples: NServiceBus, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ. All of those support pubsub and has .net clients

Comment: Are there any reasons why you cant/dont want to use IIS server? In .NET you can use remoting and create listeners on your clients to be notified of any changes on your server....

Comment: @pebrian I didnt know these existed, I'll take a look. @Eduard I try to stick as much as I can to open source - but thanks, I'll take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I'd consider using a WCF service that implements a [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) technique. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/09/scale-wcf-application-better-with-asynchronous-programming.aspx) gives some details on scaling the WCF service efficiently.

For notifications that there is new data in the database, if you are using SQL Server, try [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It allows you to set up an event that fires in your code whenever the result of a given query changes. I've used it effectively for just this sort of thing.